# Graphical Traceroute with Map from Repository

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, traceroute

It seems like `xt` (xtraceroute) has been dropped from the repository, does anyone know of another graphical traceroute program in the main repos which draws maps? If not, then a loose deb package will do, or a PPA.

Comment: http://vtrace.mx4492.in is a little online tool I hacked together as an alternative. See if that serves your purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try  [Open Visual Traceroute](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvisualtrace/). Available on Sourceforge. It uses Java and works well in Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04.

### 1. Install Oracle Java 7 JRE

- Open Visual Traceroute requires Oracle Java 6 JRE or newer to be installed.
- The easiest way I have found is to install Java on Ubuntu is via the Web Upd8 PPA .
- First add the PPA. Open a Terminal Window and enter :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

- A good idea to minimise any Java conflicts is to **remove OpenJDK**.  open a Terminal Window and enter :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk*
```

- To **install** Oracle **Java 7** version and make sure **gksu** is installed (removed from Ubuntu 13.04) open a Terminal Window and enter :

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer gksu
```

- **Tip:** Top check the Java version installed on your system open a terminal and enter :

```
java -version
```

### 2. Download and install Open Visual Traceroute

- Open the Terminal window and enter :

```
mkdir /tmp/OpenVisualTraceRoute
cd /tmp/OpenVisualTraceRoute
```

- Then for **32bit and 64bit systems** download and install the latest version with :

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvisualtrace/files/latest/download
sudo unzip download -d /opt/
```

- Extract the application icon to be used for the launcher and set permissions with :

```
cd /opt/OpenVisualTraceRoute*
sudo unzip -j org.leo.traceroute.jar */internet.png
sudo chmod +x startLinux.sh
```

### 3. Create an Open Visual Traceroute launcher

- To create a Ubuntu Unity **Desktop Launcher**, create a desktop launcher file with :

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/open-visual-traceroute.desktop
```

- Then add the following information and save :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Open Visual Traceroute
Version=1.3.1
GenericName=Open Visual Traceroute
X-GNOME-FullName=Open Visual Traceroute
Comment=Open Visual Traceroute
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Utility;
Exec=gksudo /bin/sh startLinux.sh
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

- Then add the path to the latest version and icon in the launcher with:

```
cd /opt/OpenVisualTraceRoute*
sudo su
echo "Path=$(eval pwd)" >> /usr/share/applications/open-visual-traceroute.desktop
echo "Icon=$(eval pwd)/internet.png" >> /usr/share/applications/open-visual-traceroute.desktop
exit
```

- You will then be able to search for **Open Visual Traceroute** in your **unity dash** and launch the application.

Original install guide can be found here : http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-install-open-visual-traceroute-ubuntu

Answer (score 8):

Package/binary `mtr` does what you need. By default (I think), Ubuntu has `mtr-tiny` installed.

It should start with a GTK window, but you can always invoke it with `mtr --gtk` or `mtr -- curses` to specify what you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention my mapping requirement in the question, it has been updated. I don't believe mtr does maps?

Comment: Awesomely handy though, I didn't know that came in the base install.

Comment: By default, only mtr-tiny is installed, which has no gtk support.  Issue "sudo apt-get install mtr" to remove this and install the full package.  Running mtr at this point will invoke the gtk interface.  But no maps, and I couldn't get it to actually work...

Comment: I needed `mtr` to work with CLI, but in my case `mtr` command was by default spawning GTK version. So, i removed `mtr` and installed `mtr-tiny`, my purpose of using CLI with `mtr` served with package `mtr-tiny` :) thank you for the clarification between `mtr-tiny` and `GTK` version.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it may require you have whois package installed:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ovtr:

ovtr depends on whois; however:  Package whois is not installed.
```

Then we would just execute:

```
sudo apt-get install whois

The following NEW packages will be installed: whois

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

After this operation, 164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main whois amd64 5.1.1 [30,2 kB]
Fetched 30,2 kB in 0s (39,8 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package whois.
(Reading database ... 355631 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/whois_5.1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking whois (5.1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up whois (5.1.1) ...
Setting up ovtr (1.6.3-1) ...
```